# Separating public interface from implementation details

Tags: c++

I have to design a `Font` class that will have multiple implementations spanning platforms or different libraries (Win32 GDI or FreeType for example). So essentially there will be single shared header/interface file and multiple .cpp implementations (selected during build time). I would prefer to keep the public interface (header file) clean from any implementation details, but this usually is hard to achieve. A font object has to drag some sort of a private state - like a handle in GDI, or FreeType face object internally.

In **C++**, what is the best way to track private implementation details? Should I use static data in implementation files?

**Edit:** Found this great article on the subject: [Separating Interface and Implementation in C++](http://www.octopull.demon.co.uk/c++/implementation_hiding.html).

p.s. I recall in Objective-C there are private categories that allow you to define a class extension in your private implementation file making quite elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the PIMPL design pattern.

This is basically where your object holds a pointer to the actual platform dependent part and passes all platform dependent calls through to this object.

#### Font.h

```
class FontPlatform;
class Font
{
   public:
       Font();
       void Stuff();
       void StuffPlatform();
   private:
       FontPlatform*  plat;
};
```

#### Font.cpp

```
#include "Font.h"
#if Win
#include "FontWindows.h"
#else
#error "Not implemented on non Win platforms"
#endif

Font::Font()
  : plat(new PLATFORM_SPCIFIC_FONT)  // DO this cleaner by using factory.
{}

void Font::Stuff()  { /* DoStuff */ }
void Font::StuffPlatform()
{
    plat->doStuffPlat();  // Call the platform specific code.
}
```

Comment: The great thing with pimpl is that the implementation classes can be polymorphic (this bears a name in the design patterns religion iirc). So indeed, you can use factories, you can also select an implementation at run time if you need to (to accomodate eg. OS variants).